# How to read gzipped data from http response in Golang

Tags: go

I have a http response which is gzipped.

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        var buf bytes.Buffer


    }
```

How can I ungzipped it and parse it into my struct?

I saw a question like this:
[Reading gzipped HTTP response in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130341/reading-gzipped-http-response-in-go)

but it output the response into a standard output. Also the example runs into error, the

```
reader, err = gzip.NewReader(response.Body)
```

returns err as "EOF". How can I debug this?

Comment: EOF indicates that there is no response body, or that it is too short to be a gzip stream. What makes you think that you have a compressed response? What makes you think it's not handled by Go automatically? How do you construct the request and client?

Comment: hi @Peter thanks for your response, I read the api document which says the response is gzipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reading this code:
https://gist.github.com/xyproto/f4915d7e208771f3adc4

here is the code which helped me.

```
// Write gunzipped data to a Writer
func gunzipWrite(w io.Writer, data []byte) error {
    // Write gzipped data to the client
    gr, err := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(data))
    defer gr.Close()
    data, err = ioutil.ReadAll(gr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    w.Write(data)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: io.Copy is often more efficient than ReadAll followed by Write.

Answer (score 2):

Golang *by default* will automatically decode the body of gzipped response. So practically you just need to read the response body and it's enough, no need to do anything afterwards.

Below is an explanation from https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport:

> ... If the Transport requests gzip on its own and gets a gzipped response, it's transparently decoded in the Response.Body. **However**, if the user explicitly requested gzip it is not automatically uncompressed.

So if you get `EOF` error, the problem might not be because the gzip encoding stuff, it could be because there is actually no data on the response body.

Btw, to you can check whether response is gzipped or not is by checking the [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding#Directives) response header.

Comment: thanks for the info, I did checked my service provider's document, the response is encoded with gzip.